# What causes this segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
    string replace_strings (FILE *in, FILE *out, char *what, char *repl)
{
    int x = strlen(what);
    int z = strlen(repl);
    string newWhat(what, x);
    string newRepl(repl, z);
    char c;
    char *str; //наш буффер
    int i = 0;
    size_t found;
```

it's a bad decision to do like this, i know

```
    while(!feof(in))
    {
        while((c!='\0') && (i<=255))
        {
            str[i] = fscanf(in, "%c", c);
            i++;
        }
        string newStr (str, i);
        while(found != string::npos)
        {
            found = newStr.find(newWhat);
            newStr.replace(found, newWhat.length(), newRepl);
        }

        fprintf(out, "%s", newStr.c_str());
```

it returns Segmentation fault, what's wrong? what should i do? Help me guys

Comment: What's the debugger telling you about the source of the error? Also, you **always** need to check whether input was successful **after** trying read something.

Comment: You don't initialize `c`, and you don't initialize `str`, so anything can happen.

Comment: Life would be easier if you didn't mix C I/O with C++ features.  For example, `std::fstream` works better with `std::string` than `fprintf` does.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `strlen`.  The `std::string` constructor will create a C++ string without needing the length parameter.

Comment: Also, there's error in comment - should be "буфер" - with one "ф".

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate memory for `str`. Use [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), and forget about clumsy buffers.

Comment: When reading data you want to use `std::istringstream`, not `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Also, when reading data from a file or keyboard, use `std::getline` with `std::string`.  Don't mix `std::string` and `char *`.  Stick with one or the other.